# how to bind a model to another in laravel

Tags: laravel, model-binding

some packages comes pre-packed with its own models ex.`Cart` but sometimes i want to add some extra logic to that model,

so instead of editing the original model or searching everywhere where this model was used and replace it with the newly created one,

i thought i would use app bind ex.

```
// model
<?php

namespace App\Binders;

use some\package\Models\Cart;

class CartBinder extends Cart
{
    // extra logic
}


// AppServiceProvider@register
$this->app->bind('some\package\Models\Cart', 'App\Binders\CartBinder');
```

but sadly this has no effect & am not sure what i've missed :(.

Answer (score 2):

I'll suggest you decorate the model using the Decorator pattern.
Jeff Way has a good series [Design Patterns](https://laracasts.com/series/design-patterns-in-php/episodes/1) 
or check this [decorator pattern example](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator/php).
It could go along the line:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Binders;

use some\Package\Models\Cart;

class CartBinder
{
    protected $cart;

    public function __contruct(Cart $cart)
    {
        $this->cart = $cart;
    }

    // the extra logic

}
```

Then You can bind the dependencies in the Service Container.

```
$this->app->bind('App\Binders\CartBinder', function ($app) {
    return new \App\Binders\CartBinder(new some\Package\Models\Cart);
});
```

From there you can resolve it, instantiate somewhere in your code (controllers, models...) this way:

```
$cart = $this->app->make('App\Binders\CartBinder');
```

Or you could inject in your controller's method.

```
// use App\Binders\CartBinder;

// ...

public function store(CartBinder $cart)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: but how laravel will know that i want to use this model not the original `some\Package\Models\Cart` ?

Comment: the question title is "how to bind a model to another in laravel" not how to build a new implementation.

Comment: @ctf0 my approach is just a full explanation of the steps you have to take to make it work. You can see the doc on model binding in Laravel 5.4
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#binding
Extending the model you need to bind won't make it work. You have to pass the model to bind in the constructor.

Comment: so the short answer is "we cant bind a model" and we simply have to create a new one.